# Opening a Scala Play console and executing commands programmatically

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Scala script that accesses models from my Play project and rather than open up a console and run it manually, I would like it to be run automatically after a Git hook.  This could be achieved via a small bash script but there doesn't seem to be a way to execute the ":load nameOfMyScript.scala" command after the Play console has opened.  Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

I also considered running this command via a plain Scala console but I cannot figure out how to load my Play project definition inside of the Scala console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a must read: http://kailuowang.blogspot.hk/2013/05/define-arbitrary-tasks-in-play-21.html

Comment: Oops I found that link was way to old to cover sbt 0.13...

Answer (score 1):

From the `sbt` console of your Play app, run the `console` command.  This will start the Scala REPL and give you access to everything on your app's classpath.